# Why are there elementary equations that are not solvable in closed form?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, special-functions, closed-form-expressions

Elementary equations and closed-form solutions can be important in mathematics and in the natural sciences, e.g. for discovering and describing certain relationships.

$\log\colon x\mapsto\log(x)$; $x\neq 0$; $-\pi<\Im(\log(x))\leq\pi$ for all $x$

$\mathbb{L}$ denotes the [Liouvillian numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillianNumber.html) (= Elementary numbers). $\mathbb{L}$ is the smallest field that contains $\mathbb{Q}$ and is closed under algebraic operations, $\exp$ and $\log$. The Elementary numbers are divided into the explicit elementary numbers and the implicit elementary numbers.
$i\in\mathbb{L}$

In [Chow 1999], Chow cites [Lin 1983] and writes:
"Let $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ denote the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then Lin's result is the following.
**Theorem 1.** If Schanuel's conjecture is true and $f(x,y)\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x,\exp(x)]$ is an irreducible polynomial involving both $x$ and $y$ and $f(\alpha,\exp(\alpha))=0$ for some nonzero $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, then $\alpha\notin\mathbb{L}$."

Chow continues: "The reader may check that our arguments generalize readily to other transcendental equations such as $x=\cos\ x$."
$ $

**1. Can Lin's theorem be generalized to all irreducible polynomials $f$ with $f(x,y,z)\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x,\exp(x),\exp(ix)]$ involving $x$, $y$ and $z$, or $x$ and ($y$ or $z$)?**
$ $

**2. Can Lin's theorem be generalized to all irreducible polynomials $f$ with $f(x,y,z)\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x,\exp(A_1(x)),\exp(A_2(ix))]$ involving $x$, $y$ and $z$, or $x$ and ($y$ or $z$), wherein $A_1$ and $A_2$ are arbitrary algebraic functions?**
$ $

**3. To which kinds of Elementary equations can Lin's theorem further be generalized?**
This question is necessary, because Ritt's and Risch's elementary invertibility of elementary functions ([How to extend Ritt's theorem on elementary invertible bijective elementary functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320801/how-to-extend-ritts-theorem-on-elementary-invertible-bijective-elementary-funct)) is not the whole answer for solving equations elementary.
$\ $

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

Comment: What does "closed under log" mean? It is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing *every* determination of $\log(x)$ whenever it contains $x\neq 0$?

Comment: I added this to my question now. Chow has therefore an extra definition for "closed under $exp$ and $log$".

Comment: You added the clarification that the argument of $\log$ should be nonzero, but this was not the important part of my comment: my question is whether one demands that **every determination** of the logarithm (or equivalently, $2i\pi$) belongs to the field.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: That seems to follow from the OP's latest version, as $i\pi = \log (-1) - \log 1 \in L$ (or slightly modify this, depending on what is meant by "main branch").

Comment: Question 2 seems trivial as stated, since we can take $A_1(x)=ix,\ A_2(x)=x$.

Comment: To see whether 1 and 2 work, presumably you look at Schanuel's conjecture.  Even if they are presumably true, they may not follow from Schanuel in the same way as Theorem 1 does.

Comment: This would seem to be related to a more recent question from the same user, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364901/why-some-kinds-of-elementary-transcendental-equations-cannot-be-solved-by-elemen