# Irreducibility of equations of algebraic expressions of two variables?

Tags: polynomials

I want to try to find some new answers about solvability of equations of elementary expressions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

I'm asking in MathOverflow because transformation of equations of algebraic expressions of more than one variable to irreducible polynomial equations is sophisticated.

Let
$A(x,y)$ be an algebraic expression involving exactly both $x$ and $y$,
$n\in\mathbb{N}_+$,
$P_1(x,y),...,P_n(x,y)\in\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x,y]\setminus(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[x]\cup\overline{\mathbb{Q}}[y])$, each $P_i(x,y)$ **irreducible** ($i\in\{1,...,n\}$).

What general types of equations

$$A(x,y)=0$$

can be transformed to equations

$$P_1(x,y)\cdot...\cdot P_n(x,y)=0$$

where the solution set of the second equation does contain the solutions of the first equation?

The equation $A(x,y)=0$ can be a polynomial equation, a rational equation or a radical equation.

Trivial cases are $A(x,y)=P_1(x,y)\cdot...\cdot P_n(x,y)=0$ and $A(x,y)=\frac{P_1(x,y)\cdot...\cdot P_n(x,y)}{Q}=0$ where $Q$ is an arbitrary nonzero expression which doesn't contain a factor $P_i(x,y)$.

(Until now, I could find only one more case: [Extension of closed-form solvability of polynomial equations of x and exp to rational expressions?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365029/extension-of-closed-form-solvability-of-polynomial-equations-of-x-and-exp-to-rat) .)