# If $x^x=2$ then is $x$ expressible using elementary functions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions, irrational-numbers

I have a curious question. Let $x∈\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $x^x=2$. I am aware that the Gelfond–Schneider theorem implies that $x$ cannot be algebraic. However, is it still possible that $x$ can be expressed in terms of elementary functions applied to rationals? I saw [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/135911) but that is concerning the whole Lambert-W function and not a single point. Is anything known about this $x$? If not, is anything known about the cardinality of $\{ x : x∈E ∧ x^x=c ∧ c∈\mathbb{Q}^+ ∖ \{ k^k : k∈\mathbb{Z}^+ \} \}$, where $E$ is defined as the set of all reals that can be expressed using elementary functions applied to rationals?

By "elementary function applied to rationals" I mean any of the following:

- Rational functions with rational coefficients
- Exponential function
- The inverse of any of the above
- The composition of any of the above
- Constants $0,1,i$

Since some people want a precise definition of "inverse", here is one: For any meromorphic function $f$, let $f^{-1}(z)$ be defined as $w = re^{it}$ where $r∈\mathbb{R}_{≥0}$ and $0≤t<2π$ iff $f(w) = z$ and $r$ is minimum and then $t$ is minimum. If no such $w$ exists then $f^{-1}(z)$ is undefined.

Comment: As usual for questions of this sort, you need to define what an elementary function is.  The most obvious definition allows constant functions, but then all reals are so expressible!  Chow's "[What is a closed-form number?](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1999.12005066)" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1699262)) provides one possible way of formulating the question.

Comment: @LSpice: I see I have to be more specific since for some reason constant functions are elementary...

Comment: Isn't $E$ countable?  That would give your set cardinality at most $\aleph_0$.  And it's trivially at least $\aleph_0$ because of $1^1, 2^2, 3^3, \dots$.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Argh of course. I wanted something other than those trivial solutions. Sorry about that.

Comment: Downvoters should explain why they think this question is not fit for MO.

Comment: Do we even know, for example, that $x$ is not a rational multiple of $e$? As far as I know it is not known if $e^e$ is rational.

Comment: isn't this basically asking whether the Lambert W-function can be expressed in terms of elementary functions? this MSE posting seems relevant --- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2161098/87355

Comment: @CarloBeenakker OP linked this exact thread in the question. As they remark, the linked post is about the function, but this question is (essentially) about *specific values* of Lambert W. Even nonelementary functions can take elementary values.

Comment: Won't every $x\in E$ belong to the set you query about? Since if $x$ is elementary, so is $x^x$. The less trivial question is for $x^x\in E$ but $x\not\in E$; presumably "most" (in some sense) $x$ with $c=x^x\in E$ will not belong to $E$, like the example with $c=2$ (which I would bet many of my marbles on not being elementary).

Comment: @wojowu, yes; this is why I downvoted. This sort of question is only worth asking if you use a definition that’s already been tested elsewhere, or if your definition is unusually good and precise (saying “the inverse” is not good enough). The OP is making too many errors and changes to get that right.

Comment: The question is good but difficult. An easier qiestion would be wheher the number  $x$ can be computed in linear time (that is, there is a Turing machine computing an $n$th decimal (or binary) approximation of $x$ in linear time.

Comment: @Wojowu: I fixed the mistake. I was thinking about the function mapping $c>0$ to $x$ such that $x^x=c$, and thinking about what happens when it is applied to rationals, but mistakenly put "$c∈E$" instead.

Comment: @MarkSapir I don’t think that’s any easier, as we lack tools to separate linear time from slightly super-linear time. (Note that the number is computable in time $O(M(n)\log n)$, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Elementary_functions); that’s $O(n(\log n)^2)$ using the best known multiplication algorithm.) Also, I’m not sure how is it relevant, as the vast majority of constants defined by elementary functions are *also* likely not computable in linear time.

Comment: @EmilJerabek: Ok, slightly more than linear is also fine. The more so that this does not lead to a discussion about how  many tapes the TM should have. Are  all elementary numbers computable in polynomial  time?

Comment: @MarkSapir They are all computable in time $O(M(n)\log n)$ (i.e., $O(n(\log n)^2)$), as that is the complexity of elementary functions. And as witnessed here, this also holds if you throw in Lambert’s function, and more generally the inverse of any (sufficiently smooth) function that you can already construct. I stress that here, computing $x$ means, given $n$, compute an $n$-digit *approximation* of $x$, i.e., something within distance (1/2 of the value of the last digit position) from $x$, but not necessarily smaller than $x$. If you really need to compute the $n$th digit of the infinite ...

Comment: ... decimal expansion of $x$, the $O(M(n)\log n)$ time algorithm only works if you know a bound on the irrationality measure of $x$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek3.0: You can probably throw in any function which is a solution of a ODE whose  coefficients are elementary functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is really an extended comment.

As Dan Richardson explains in his paper [The elementary constant problem](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/143242.143284), there are different classes of numbers that you might be interested in. Your number certainly belongs to what is now usually called the class of *elementary numbers*, because it is a solution to the system of equations
$$\eqalign{e^z &= 2 \cr xy&=z \cr e^y&= x\cr}$$
Now one could ask whether your number is a *Liouvillian number*, meaning that it's obtained by a finite
sequence of algebraic, exponential, or logarithmic extensions of the rationals.  But this allows for a more generous definition of "inverse" than you seem to want.  As LSpice noted in a comment, you could also ask whether your number is a closed-form number in the sense of [my paper](http://alum.mit.edu/www/tchow/closedform.pdf), but this may be a more restrictive class than you want.

In any case, I think that the answer to your question is likely to be unknown since these types of questions tend to be very difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, this was just a question out of curiosity, and I just want to know if any result of this sort is known, whether with more or less restrictive classes of 'nice' numbers. Ordinarily, I expect such questions to be beyond known mathematics, but I have seen surprising results (to me) before.