# Do we have an algorithm for comparing $e^e$ with rationals?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, constructive-mathematics, transcendental-number-theory, decidability

Do we have an algorithm for comparing $e^e$ with rationals, with a known time to convergence?

In a non-constructive sense, there obviously is an algorithm.

- If $e^e$ is some rational $q_0$, then we can decide if a rational $q$ is bigger than or smaller than or equal to $e^e$ by comparing it with $q_0$.
- If $e^e$ is irrational, then we calculate the sequences
  $$z_n =\left(1+\frac{\small{1}}{n}\right)^n$$
  $$a_n = \left(1+\frac{z_n}{n}\right)^n$$
  $$\phantom{2+}b_n = \left(1+\frac{z_n}{n}\right)^{n+2}$$
  If $a_n>q$, then $e^e>q$; and if $b_n<q$, then $e^e<q$. Since $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge to $e^e$ from below and from above, the algorithm is guaranteed to terminate with an $n$ that meets one or the other criterion.

I'd like to know an algorithm's convergence time in advance, just as for the algorithm [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345810/algorithm-for-comparing-x-y-cdot-logz-for-x-y-z-rational/378064#378064) comparing $e^t$ and $u$ for any rationals $t$ and $u$. Do we have such an algorithm for $e^e$?

*Update:* We can also phrase this as comparing
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{p}{q}n!} - \sqrt[n]{\phantom{\frac{p}{q}}\! \! \! \! \! n!}$$
with 1, since the limit is just $\log(p/q)/e$.

Comment: I feel like this will depend on how much we know about Diophantine approximations of $e^e$. Do we for instance know this number is *not* Liouville?

Comment: @Wojowu, I don't know whether $e^e$ is Liouville, and I hope this problem is easier than that. Perhaps "Diophantine approximation" is a better tag than "transcendental number theory".

Comment: sage can compute the convergents of the continued fraction.

Comment: @joro Using convergents for provable running time upper bounds requires upper bounds on how fast we can compute the continued fraction, and if you think about it, it actually requires knowing how to compare $e^e$ to rationals - in the definition of partial quotients we take floors, and to do that we need to determine if some rational expression in $e^e$ is larger or smaller than an integer.

Comment: The continued fraction is in OEIS: https://oeis.org/A064107

Answer (score 7):

I am pretty sure that no such algorithm is known.  Note that in particular, such an algorithm would solve the *zero recognition problem* for numbers of the form $e^e - p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers. Known zero recognition algorithms for elementary constants, such as the one described in [Zero tests for constants in simple scientific computations](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11786-007-0002-x) by Daniel Richardson (*Math. Comp. Sci.* **1** (2007), 21–37), always assume Schanuel's conjecture or some special case thereof; in your case, that amounts to assuming that $e^e$ is irrational, which is unknown.

Of course, there could still be a known zero recognition algorithm for $e^e - p/q$ since that's a very special case, but it would have to take advantage of some special feature of $e^e$ beyond the fact that it is (what I call) a [closed-form number](http://alum.mit.edu/www/tchow/closedform.pdf), and I don't think anything like that is known.  For example, I don't think we can even rigorously rule out the possibility that there is a sequence of rational numbers $(p_n/q_n)$ such that $|e^e - p_n/q_n| = 1/f(n)$ for some increasing function $f$ that grows faster than any computable function [**EDIT:** This statement is wrong; see comments below].  Of course, nobody believes such a thing, but closed-form numbers can behave worse than you might think; see for example [Counterexamples to the uniformity conjecture](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.comgeo.2004.02.005), again by Daniel Richardson (along with Elsonbaty, *Comput. Geom.* **33** (2006), 58–64).

Comment: Thanks -- I'm hoping that someone might find an answer for $e^e$ even though the general case is open. If the evidence is inconclusive even for this (which I consider the simplest case not covered by Baker's theorem plus standard algebra) then the evidence for Schanuel's conjecture looks less persuasive than I thought.

Comment: @MattF. : I'm puzzled why you think that this has anything to do with evidence for Schanuel's conjecture. Nothing along these lines was known for Baker's theorem before Baker proved it. Would you therefore have thought, before the proof, that the evidence for Baker's theorem was weak?

Comment: Are there consequences of Schanuel's conjecture that have been proved which don't already follow from Baker's theorem? The support for the conjecture seems tenuous if it all comes through one source. Meanwhille for Baker's theorem, the Gelfond-Schneider theorem and the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem provided two independent bits of evidence. But I'm happy to be corrected if my impressions are wrong or if there are some good examples.

Comment: @MattF. : Some special cases of Schanuel's conjecture are given in Chapter 12 of Baker's book _Transcendental Number Theory_. But I would say that the main reason people expect Schanuel's conjecture to be true is that it seems very hard to imagine that it could be false. For example, what evidence do we have that $e+\pi$ is irrational? None, if you demand rigorous proofs. But it boggles my mind to imagine that $e+\pi$ could be rational.

Comment: Richardson's zero-recognition result, IIRC, has the property that if there is a failure of Schanuel's conjecture then it will report it. Since algorithms of this form have been implemented and run repeatedly with no surprises, that could be regarded as computational evidence for Schanuel's conjecture.

Comment: @TimothyChow Richardson's algorithm will fail to terminate if it encounters a counterexample to Schanuel's conjecture. Also, Richardson's algorithm has never (to my knowledge) been implemented; computer algebra systems use weaker heuristics.

Comment: The Richardson-Elsonbaty paper on counterexamples is pleasantly easy to read, and one of the strong versions of their final conjecture is easy to quote: An expression of depth $d$ using integers no larger than $H$ can not have a value in between $0$ and $\max(H,2)^{-2^d}$.

Comment: On the topic of evidence for Schanuel's conjecture, there is a theorem of Rosenlicht that is arguably a sort of function-field analogue of Schanuel's conjecture. I describe Rosenlicht's theorem in [another MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/373653).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your remark involving $|e^e-p_n/q_n|=1/f(n)$. If you literally mean what you wrote, then this will always hold for some sequence of rationals by taking $q_n$ "uncomputably large". If you meant $p_n,q_n$ computable, then the function $\lceil 1/|e^e-p_n/q_n|\rceil$ is computable - this is trivial if $e^e$ is rational, and if not then we just compute the successive approximations. We can't give explicit bounds, but we know $f(n)$ won't outgrow all computable functions.

Comment: @Wojowu: You are right. What I had in mind was (a generalization of) the fact that we don't know an algorithm for computing the $n$th digit of $e^e$, because if the decimal expansion at some point looks like (say) $49999999\ldots$ then we don't know how far out we might have to go to settle the question of whether the $4$ should be a $5$. But I garbled the statement.